# Is there a processing / memory difference between Dataframe.copy(deep=False) shallow copy ot just assigning one dataframe to another?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Is one of these better to create a link (I am not trying to make a deep copy) than the other? If so how?

```
df1 = pd.dataframe(stuff goes here)
df2 = df1.copy(deep=False)
```

**And**

```
df1 = pd.dataframe(stuff goes here)
df2 = df1
```

Comment: `df2 = df1` doesn't actually do anything. It binds the same data to another name, no movement/copying occurs, see [this post](https://nedbatchelder.com/text/names1.html) for more detail

Answer (score 1):

As far as I have come across, using `.copy(deep=False)` carries the benefit of clarity for reading your code. When copying and referencing are both occurring, messy code can make it difficult to keep track of what is going on and can potentially cause unexpected issues. If you use `copy()` and specify whether `deep` is True or False, you end up with cleaner code that can be easier to debug.